# How to adjust clickable div width and hight for both iphone and ipad screen?

Tags: html, ios, css

I want the clickable divs to fit iphone 6 screen size(one in each row) and on ipad two clickable divs in one row .could any one show me how i achieve this task .Thanks in advance.

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">


</head>

<body>


<section id="MainSection" class ="programs">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="section-title">
<h2>
<a id="main_content" href="./secionOne">Section one</a>
</h2>
</div>

<div class ="image">
    <a href="..." style="display: block; height: 100%">
        <img src="./1.jpg" alt=".." />
    </a>
</div>


<div class ="image">
    <a href="..." style="display: block; height: 100%">
        <img src="./2.jpg" alt=".." />
    </a>
</div>

</div> 
</div> 
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you looked into using any grid systems like Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two big containers (.container and .row); one is unecessary. So delete it. Then, you have two ways to accomplish your objective:

**1**- Let the container flex like this:

```
.container {  
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
}
```

**2**- Or use `float:left;` on your .image divs like this:

```
.image {  
  float: left;  
}
```

**After perform one of these options, set the .image divs width of 50% and add a media query to let it takes the entire screen width on small devices:**

```
@media (max-width: 740px){
.image {
  width: 100%;
}
}
```

**Finally**, add `box-sizing: border-box;` on the elements with margin/padding > zero to avoid the total width sum of being more than 100% and use this following css to avoid the gap between rows when the image falls to the next line:

```
img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

**Demo**: [**Codepen Flex;**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QNyBpP)

**Demo**: [**Codepen Float.**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZbymr)

Comment: Thanks for replies. <style>
.container {
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
</style> worked well for iphone screen but how to make new style for ipad so two divs fit in one row (and gap between the two divs and gap on left and right of the row) ?Note : I can check if the user agent is iphone or ipad and use different style for each devices!

Comment: When there is enought space, they will be in a single row. I did an update to the answer with an example, check it please;

Comment: I tested your updated code on ipad 2 still one big image in one row and big gap between each row and big gap on right side of image! I want two image in one row and gap between the two image and on the right and left of the screen! Can this be done using separate style (by checking user agent for iphone and ipad and use different style for each device )?

Comment: user agent is a complicated thing, and things must be simple. be aware of the height/width size of the elements;

Comment: Thanks i posted before your second update so now i get two image in one row on ipad screen(.image {  
  float: left;  
}).  how i can adjust the gap between rows on ipad (it is reasonable size on iPhone but a little big on ipad) ?

Comment: use `line-height: 20px;` (with the number that you wish) on the body (all page) or in a single container.

Comment: if you need to avoid elements on the around the floated elements, use `clear:left` `clear:right` or `clear:both`

Comment: should i add line-height: 20px; to image style or row ? how about adding white gap on right and left site of each and between tow image in one row ?

Comment: the number 20 was just an example, use the number that you want. You can use it on body like `body { line-heiht: NUMBERpx` (and change the entire page line height) or just in a container like `.row { line-heiht:NUMBERpx` (reaching only the container content).

Comment: unfortunately the width of original image that i use is big so on iphone it exceeds the width of iphone 6 and on ipad two images doesn't show in same row as intended! Any solution for it ?(i removed  style="display: block; height: 100%" from href)

Comment: you can set the div max-width to 50%, be aware let the body margin equal to zero and if youre using any padding or border on an element set its `box-sizing:border-box`. If the div is a block level element set its font-size to zero. A good website to you test your website in different devices: [**troylabs**](http://troy.labs.daum.net/)

Comment: for iphone this didn't make the image smaller so it fit the width of iphone :div.{
    width:50%;
}

Comment: don't forget to set the body size `body { width:100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px;`

Comment: If you have it online you can pass me the link so i can take a better look and test it;

Comment: if you mean the image . Here is url for a sample image size that deal with:http://s14.postimg.org/r68yyomap/image.jpg

Comment: [**check this demo link**](http://freestock.tk/demorows.html) and make a copy because i dont know how many longer it will stand online.

Comment: Many thanks i copied it .I tested on both iphone and ipad it works as i intended!:-) if you update your above post i will accept it as an answer

Comment: forget the line-height; just set `img { vertical-align:top;` and you'll kill that white space between the rows [**(link)**](http://freestock.tk/demorows.html). *ps: next time let the original image avaible on the question, makes a lot of difference when you work with a diferent media/scenario*;

Comment: updated. ps: you can change the @media query to the values that you want; it can be min width, max width, min height, max height, a combination of these factors, the number of pixels that you want, etc;